# How combine value to be one from multiple textbox php before insert to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How get value to one field from multiple textbox?

i have example 3 textbox

```
<input name="post_code[]" class="input form-control" id="tbCode1" placeholder="Code 1" type="text" value="A01">
<input name="post_code[]" class="input form-control" id="tbCode2" placeholder="Code 2" type="text" value="A02">
<input name="post_code[]" class="input form-control" id="tbCode3" placeholder="Code 3" type="text" value="A03">
```

but how make the value like this

```
$postcode = 'A01,A02,A03';
```

before insert to mysql

Comment: see this link to understand in detail: http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/04/capture-array-values-from-dynamic-input-fields-using-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [implode()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp)

```
$post_code = $_POST['post_code'];
$postcode = implode(",",$post_code);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = implode(",", $_POST['post_code']);
echo $a;
```